# React Bootstrap Nav.Link href/onSelect issues

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap NavLink to main navigation. What I'm trying to do is:

1. Allow opening in new tab with correct route (no checking if it should be left needed)
2. If user wants to change current tab page - check if it should be left (eg some changes on current page may not be saved)

My current version looks like this:

```
 {paths && paths.map(path => 
   <NavLink href={path} onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}>
      {path}
   </NavLink>
 }
```

And works quite alright, but the problem starts when my url looks like domain.com/a/b. Let's assume I click on c, navLink creates route domain.com/a/c instead of domain.com/c. I tried using `` href={`/${path}`} `` and routing worked fine but it was ignoring `onSelect`.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be solved? Is that even possible to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe instead of `onSelect` you should set `onClick` ?

Comment: It behaves exactly the same (ignored when `/${path}` and works ok with {path} but provided path is wrong)